# How to return different Http Status Code in ServiceStack

Tags: c#, servicestack

Hi I am very new to Service Stack and am wondering how can I return a different http status code.

The ones that I need be able to return are:

1. 204 - processed but no content
2. 400 - bad request
3. 404 - not found
4. 422 - for validation issues
5. 500 - internal server error

Can Anyone help?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If your Service doesn't return a response, e.g. has a `void` method or returns `null`, ServiceStack automatically returns a **204 No Content** response status.

This behavior can be reverted to an empty **200 OK** response with:

```
SetConfig(new HostConfig {
    Return204NoContentForEmptyResponse = false
});
```

> Request DTOs returning empty responses should implement the `IReturnVoid` marker interface

### Custom Error Codes

All other status codes are error status codes which are documented in ServiceStack's [Error Handling docs](https://docs.servicestack.net/error-handling).

E.g. It's generally recommended to return the ideal C# `Exception` and have ServiceStack automatically return the ideal HTTP Error code.

By Default C# Exceptions inheriting from:

- `ArgumentException`, `SerializationException` or `FormatException` returns a **400 BadRequest**
- `NotImplementedException` or `NotSupportedException` returns a **405 MethodNotAllowed**
- `FileNotFoundException` is return as **404 NotFound**
- `AuthenticationException` is returned as **401 Unauthorized**
- `UnauthorizedAccessException` is returned as **403 Forbidden**
- `OptimisticConcurrencyException` is returned as **409 Conflict**
- All Other normal C# Exceptions are returned as **500 InternalServerError**

So any Exceptions inheriting `ArgumentException` which includes most of the [Fluent Validation Exceptions](https://docs.servicestack.net/validation) will automatically return the preferred **400 BadRequest**.

Other ways to customize HTTP Error Statuses include:

#### Custom mapping of C# Exceptions to HTTP Error Status

You can change what HTTP Error Status is returned for different Exception Types by configuring them with:

```cs
SetConfig(new HostConfig { 
    MapExceptionToStatusCode = {
        { typeof(CustomUnprocessableEntityException), 422 },
        { typeof(CustomerNotFoundException), 404 },
    }
});
```

#### Implementing IHasStatusCode

In addition to customizing the HTTP Response Body of C# Exceptions with 
[IResponseStatusConvertible](https://docs.servicestack.net/error-handling#implementing-iresponsestatusconvertible), 
you can also customize the HTTP Status Code by implementing `IHasStatusCode`:

```cs
public class Custom401Exception : Exception, IHasStatusCode
{
    public int StatusCode => 401;
}
```

#### Returning a HttpError

If you want even finer grained control of your HTTP errors you can either **throw** or **return** an **HttpError** letting you customize the **Http Headers** and **Status Code** and HTTP Response **body** to get exactly what you want on the wire:

```cs
public object Get(User request) 
{
    throw HttpError.NotFound($"User {request.Name} does not exist");
}
```

The above returns a **404** NotFound StatusCode on the wire and is a short-hand for:

```cs
new HttpError(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, $"User {request.Name} does not exist");
```

#### HttpError with a Custom Response DTO

The `HttpError` can also be used to return a more structured Error Response with:

```cs
var responseDto = new ErrorResponse { 
    ResponseStatus = new ResponseStatus {
        ErrorCode = typeof(ArgumentException).Name,
        Message = "Invalid Request",
        Errors = new List<ResponseError> {
            new ResponseError {
                ErrorCode = "NotEmpty",
                FieldName = "Company",
                Message = "'Company' should not be empty."
            }
        }
    }
};

throw new HttpError(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "ArgumentException") {
    Response = responseDto,
};
```